# selectively call methods within class based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, class, methods

I would like to create a class that applies a certain pandas method based on the input entered by the user.

More specifically, the class can apply pandas methods sub(), mul() or add(), where a series is subtracted, multiplied or added to different variables of a dataframe. But the class should apply only the methods specified by the user in the init, and ideally in the order specified by the user.

For example:

```
_PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS = ["add", "sub", "mul"]

class RelativeFeatures:

    def __init__(
        self,
        variables: List[Union[str, int]],
        reference: List[Union[str, int]],
        func: List[str] = _PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS,
    ) -> None:

        self.variables = variables
        self.reference = reference
        self.func = func

   def _sub(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_sub_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].sub(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

    def _add(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_add_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].add(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

    def _mul(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_mul_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].mul(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

   def transform(X):

      for method in self.func:
         # apply the method that matches the string in the list
```

So that, if a user creates the following class:

```
tr = RelativeFeatures(
   variables = ["var1", "var2]
   reference = ["var3],
   func = ["mul", "add"]
)
```

and then passes a dataframe X[["var1", "var2", "var3"]] to the transform() method, the result is

XX[["var1", "var2", "var3", "var1_mul_var3", "var2_mul_var3", "var1_add_var3", "var2_add_var3"]]

Is there a way in which I can call the methods in a specified order?

Something on these lines:

```
for function in self.func:
   apply corresponding method
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to use strings to call functions then you can create dictionary `data = {"add": self._add}` and use in loop `data[method](X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furas suggestion was great, thank you!

I post the answer here:

```
_PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS = ["add", "sub", "mul"]

class RelativeFeatures:

    def __init__(
        self,
        variables: List[Union[str, int]],
        reference: List[Union[str, int]],
        func: List[str] = _PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS,
    ) -> None:

        self.variables = variables
        self.reference = reference
        self.func = func

   def _sub(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_sub_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].sub(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

    def _add(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_add_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].add(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

    def _mul(self, X):
        for reference in self.reference:
            varname = [
                str(var) + "_mul_" + str(reference)
                for var in self.variables
            ]
            X[varname] = X[self.variables].mul(X[reference], axis=0)
        return X

   def transform(X):

       methods_dict = {
            "add": self._add,
            "mul": self._mul,
            "sub": self._sub,
       }

       for func in self.func:
            methods_dict[func](X)
       
        return X
```